# Novel about death of plankton in the sea

Tags: story-identification, novel

I don't remember the name or the author of the book but I read it in Thailand sometime before 1987.

It opens with the protagonist, a scientist?, who warns that the plankton in the sea is dying off and will soon approach apocalyptic proportions.  In the end civilization breaks down and human kind reverts to cannibalism.  Set in the USA.  It NOT "The Last Gasp" by Trevor Hoyle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Maybe you could take a look at the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there's anything else you remember that you can add to the question.  Maybe some details of the cover?

Comment: This sounds like the plotline of Soylent Green (the film, not the book)

Answer (score 5):

This might be *Waters of Death* (1967) by Irving A. Greenfield. Plankton does die out, civilization fails and the MC himself becomes a victim of cannibals.